# Retrieve non-matching values index and columns between two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to retrieve indexes and columns names of non-matching values between two dfs:

```py
df1:
     'A'     'B'     'C'
1     1       5       9
2     2       6       10
3     3       7       11
4     4       8       12
```

And

```py
df2:
     'A'     'B'     'C'
1     1       44       9
2     2       6       10
3     44       7       11
4     4       8       44
```

I try to use a function that returns a list of tuples in a following way :

Excpected output:

```py
non matching values are indexed : [(3,'A'), (1,'B'), (3,'C')]
```

What's the better way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
s = df1.ne(df2).stack()

out = s[s].index.tolist()

# one-liner version as suggested by @Ynjxsjmh
# out = df1.ne(df2).stack().loc[lambda s: s].index.tolist()
```

output: `[(1, 'B'), (3, 'A'), (4, 'C')]`

For a different order (columns first then rows, if this matters):

```
s = df1.ne(df2).unstack()

out = s[s].swaplevel().index.tolist()
```

output: `[(3, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (4, 'C')]`

Comment: I'm wondering why can't chain this with `df1.ne(df2).stack().loc[lambda s: s[s]]` instead need to use `pipe`. :/

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh you can, I don't always do it because it sometimes makes the logic easier to understand to break it in two steps. But you definitely can!

Comment: Just think up the right way is to use `df1.ne(df2).stack().loc[lambda s: s]`.

Comment: Busy IRL but I'll check in a moment. Yes exactly, `s` is already a boolean series.

Comment: Your two lines code solved my problem ! thnx @mozway